# Does passwordless login using SSH pose any security threat?

Tags: ssh, web-hosting

I’ve started using hostinger to host my small-business website and since I’m in the development phase I am having trouble with passwordless login via SSH. I tried using ssh-copy-id but could not set it up. It has worked before on other providers before incl. AWS EC2, GoDaddy and couple of other providers. I wrote a ticket to their support team and this is what I got..

[image: Support Ticket]

Does passwordless login really pose a threat? I believe it uses public-private key-exchange cryptography so it should be very secure right?

Comment: The only security threat I see here is them forcing you to use passwords to automate tasks because your passwords would have to be written in plain (or crypted but with the decryption key, which is roughly the same as in plain).

Comment: Some would argue (including myself) that key based logins are generally more secure (vs password based)... The weakest link in password based logins is usually the person logging in (endless possibilities here), a weak password that's been set, or including plaintext passwords in a script. Cut out passwords and it's likely your server is already more secure by providing one less means to exploit.

Comment: Great thanks. That’s what I thought as well. The way I see it, the only security issue is if someone were to get a hold of my laptop

Comment: As long as your user and your system has adequate security on accounts that is usually the key ingredient.